# ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I had `['PREC_MM', 'DVENTO', 'PRESS_HPA']` and `[0, 109, 914.1]`

I want to combine this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([value_list], columns=[element_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are making a list of your list.

I assume that `[0,109,914.1]` is `value_list` (or `element_list`, doesn't matter for what I say).

If you have `value_list = [0,109,914.1]`, then `value_list` is a list. When you call `pd.DataFrame([value_list]...)`, you wrap `value_list` in another list, and you are effectively sending in a list that has a single item, and that item is a list that has three elements.

try just: `df = pd.DataFrame(value_list,columns=element_list)` without the brackets around the params.

Comment: ok, now i'm having this error ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (3, 3)

Comment: please edit your original post to include the whole code block of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

element_list = ['PREC_MM', 'DVENTO', 'PRESS_HPA']
value_list = [0, 109, 914.1]
df = pd.DataFrame([value_list], columns=element_list)
```

```
   PREC_MM     DVENTO   PRESS_HPA
0        0        109       914.1
```